# Call an Activity from an extend CountDownTimer class

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a `CountDownTimer` extended class during 45 minutes.
I would like to call a new `Activity` when the `CountDownTimer` is finished (in the `onFinish`), wherever where the user is (`Activity` or `Fragment`).

How can I do that ?

This is my Counter class :

```
    public class Counter  extends CountDownTimer {

    private static long millis;
    private static Counter instance;

    private Counter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        super(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
    }

    public static Counter initInstance(){
        instance =  new Counter(2700000, 1000);
        return instance;
    }

    public static Counter  getInstance() throws Exception{
        if(instance==null){
            throw new Exception("Parameters not initialized. Initiate with initInstance");
        } else{
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public boolean isFinish(){
        return millis <= 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        millis = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL A NEW ACTIVITY !
    }
}
```

I call my Counter like this :

```
Counter counterClass = Counter.initInstance();
counterClass.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to send a Context to the constructor of your Counter, save it in your counter as an attribute, and then call your counter like this :

```
Counter counterClass = Counter.initInstance(getApplicationContext());
counterClass.start();
```

And then in your finish you can start an activity normally:

```
context.startActivity()
```